# Javascript / JQuery loading current date on first load, but saving date after changing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap's Datepicker, and I want to load the current page when a user first visits the page, but after they select a different date and move to another page, I want to continue using that new selected date. I am fine using the local memory to do this. Below is what I have so far, but it's not working. It'll save the date when I change pages, but it's not loading the current date on first load.

How do I do this? Thanks!

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd;
            }

            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm;
            }
            var today = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy;
            document.getElementById("datepicker").value = localStorage.getItem("selected_date")
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                fixedHeader: true,
                pageLength: 50
            });
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            });
            $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function (event) {
                selected_date = event.format();
                localStorage.setItem("selected_date", selected_date)
            });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker" width="276" value=today>
```

Comment: What results are you getting? Your logic seems correct.

Comment: When I first load the page, the date input box is empty. Once I select a new date, it works and is saved in the localStorage and works fine, but it doesn't load the current date when I am first loading the page for some reason.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: What server side language are you using and are you using cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to conditionally set the value of the datepicker upon page load instead of always attempting to get the `localStorage` value because on the first page load, there won't be any `localStorage` value:

```
let dp = document.getElementById("datepicker");
let savedDate = localStorage.getItem("selected_date");
if(savedDate) {
  dp.value = savedDate;
} else {
  // Set default value of datepicker here
  dp.datetimepicker({
    date: new Date();
  });
}
```